# Java fields validation mechanism

Tags: java, validation

Can you recommend any mechanism/technology/3rd party jar that does field validation (like field length validation, regexp validations and so on..)?

It's **important** that it would be highly configurable - meaning that I would be able to map between fields to a set of validations or something of that sort.

Perhaps it should have also the ability to implement custom validators.

Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javax.validation` ([JSF 303 - Bean Validation)](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)

Hibernate validator is the reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Spring validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html) particularly the [PropertyEditor part](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration)

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a package for this http://commons.apache.org/validator/ 
Struts has this built-in as well